# Updating cloud code in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-cloud-code

I am new to AWS elastic beanstalk. I have deployed the Parse example server using deploy to AWS button in the [Parse Server Example Link](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example). I want to update the cloud code in main.js but I don't know how can I deploy the cloud code the way I was deploying with Parse in terminal.[commands applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35665778/how-to-deploy-cloud-code-on-aws-hosted-parse-server/36762818?noredirect=1#comment61107555_36762818) .I am trying to upload cloud code but its not updating I used eb init,eb create,eb deploy from parse server folder but after is run eb deploy its updating but application version is creating but cloud code is not updated..Could anyone help me out with another solution?

Comment: eb is a great way to go. any chance you are miss-using it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.First I have used eb init in parse server folder downloaded from http://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example and then used eb create command and changed cloud function name from hello to hi and then used eb deploy..but not working could you help me out with the steps to deploy?